# Arrays Logical error in output...?

Tags: java, arrays, search

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Sal {

public static void main (String args []){
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    String area[]=new String [10];
    int pincode[]=new int [10];
    int search;
    int chk=0;
    int p=0;
    System.out.println("Enter 10 areas");
    for (int i=0;i<=9;i++)
        area[i]=s.next();
    System.out.println("Enter 10 pincodes");
    for (int l=0;l<=9;l++)
        pincode[l]=s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Search");
    search=s.nextInt();
    for (int j=0;j<=9;j++){
        if(search == pincode[j] ){
            chk=1;
            j=p;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(chk==1){
        System.out.println("Search Found "+"Pincode : "+area[p] );
    }else{
        System.out.println("Search not Found");
    }

}

}
```

I seem to get the first part of the program right, i.e it tells me if the search is found or not found. But, after that no matter what I enter as the pincode I get the very first entered area as the search result. Suppose I enter 10 areas - pincodes , say

```
q - 1
w - 2
e - 3
r - 4 
t - 5 
y - 6
u - 7
i - 8
o - 9
p - 0
```

If I enter search as `"4"`
I get the output :

```
Search Found Pincode : q
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
j=p;
```

change it to  `p=j`:

```
   if(search == pincode[j] ){
        chk=1;
        p = j; // you want to save index
        break;
    }
```

---

Not related with your problem, but change `s.next()` to `s.nextLine()`.

`next()` will get the current word and go to next word in the same line, for example:
If your input were like this:

> in put  
>   is a    
>   string  
>   and the 
>   in put  
>   complete

the output array will be like this `[in,put,is,a,string,and,the,in,put,complete]`

But `nextLine()` will get the entire line and go to next line.

`[in put,is a, string, and the, in put, complete,....]`